# responsive background, doenst show any background

Tags: css, responsive-design

i need some help with the css properties of the responsive background, i add;

```
/* =Global
----------------------------------------------- */
homeContent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://mariovital.com/zaask/wpcontent/uploads/2014/05/fundo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#mainBG {
    background-image: url(http://mariovital.com/zaask/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/fundo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    no-repeat scroll;
    background-position:center;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;*/
}
```

also have the responsive css for the media

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    #mainBG { 
    background: url(http://mariovital.com/zaask/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/fundo.png) 50% 0 no-repeat scroll !important;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
         -moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 }
}
 @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
 #mainBG { 
   background: url(http://mariovital.com/zaask/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/fundo.png) 50% 80% no-repeat scroll !important;
background-position:center;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
   #mainBG { 
      background: url(blank.png) 75% 80% no-repeat scroll !important;
  background-position:center;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
 } 
}
```

i believe that everything its ok here... but is doesnt show on my web page what i doing wrong ?

http:/mariovital.com/zaask

any help will be apreciated !
thz in advanced

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvital/bXe9E/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #mainBG has no dimensions. Try:

```
#mainBG {
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: how can i dont remember that !! its working now, but the logo link inst working ( see the site ) 
[link]http://mariovital.com/zaask

Comment: Give ypur #mainBG a z-index: -1;